# Hibernate swaps columns around when creating a table. Why on earth does it do it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Here's an MRE:

```java
package com.example.h2_demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Sql(
        executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD,
        scripts = {"/create_user_table.sql", "/insert_user.sql"}
)
public class H2DemoApplicationTest {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public H2DemoApplicationTest(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Test
    void testNothing() {
    }

    @Test
    void getUsers() {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(users).asList().hasSize(1);
        User actualUser = users.get(0);
        User expectedUser = expectedUser();
        assertThat(actualUser.getId()).isEqualTo(expectedUser.getId());
        assertThat(actualUser.getName()).isEqualTo(expectedUser.getName());
        assertThat(actualUser.getLastName()).isEqualTo(expectedUser.getLastName());
    }

    private User expectedUser() {
        User expectedUser = new User();
        expectedUser.setId(1L);
        expectedUser.setName("John");
        expectedUser.setLastName("Doe");
        return expectedUser;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.h2_demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class H2DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(H2DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.h2_demo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

```java
package com.example.h2_demo;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Setter
@Getter
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(50)
);
```

```sql
INSERT INTO users
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe');
```

```
# application-test.properties

# show SQL executed by Hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true

# show meta comments in Hibernate statements (as specified by org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Meta annotations)
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true

# to enable line breaks and indentation in logged queries executed by Hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace

logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE

# to see what @Sql scripts are executed
logging.level.org.springframework.test.context.jdbc=DEBUG

# to see what @Sql statements are executed
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init=DEBUG
```

Result:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
expected: "John"
 but was: "Doe"
Expected :"John"
Actual   :"Doe"
```

From the logs:

```
Hibernate: 
    drop table if exists users cascade 
Hibernate: 
    create table users (
        id bigint generated by default as identity,
        last_name varchar(255),
        name varchar(255),
        primary key (id)
    )
```

See? Hibernate messed up the order of the columns. I can, of course, disable that `ddl-auto` (or specify columns in the DML script), but I'm curious why Hibernate dropped the ball with such a simple task. Never seen anything like that. Does Hibernate guarantee that table columns would be created in exactly the same order as the fields in a corresponding entity? If not, why not? It's beyond my comprehension completely

Comment: 1) No one uses ddl-auto. You should use a proper DB migration tool like Flyway. 2) Instead of creating users using SQL, create them using your own Repository. This way you won't have to spend time maintaining the script if the table changes. And also it allows you to create users dynamically for each test separately - a user that's needed for that particular test, with specifics needed for that test. 3) And sure, the order of columns most likely isn't guaranteed to match the order of fields. I'd be surprised if it did. I doubt Java maintains the order - they're probably stored in a Hash Table.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev `@Sql` is common practice for tests (though disabling ddl-auto is probably a common practice too)

Comment: Yes, it is a common practice. But not a good one. In software development there are a lot of commonly used poor practices. Try this out: http://qala.io/blog/test-data-management.html

Comment: An easy solution is to add the column names in your SQL statement: INSERT INTO users (id, name, last_name) VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe'); Doing so will remove your need to know how Hibernate creates it's DDL which could change in the future. I agree with @StanislavBashkyrtsev, best practice is to create your data programmatically (or by annotation) with your test case.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev btw, how exactly do you imagine that? Now, I inject only the repository I want to test. But if I need to perform some `@BeforeEach` inserts, I also need to inject `AccountRepository`, `CreditRepository`, `CreditOrderRepository`, `ProductRepository` (you get the idea)... So my `CardRepositoryTest` turns into an `EveryRepositoryTest` since it can fail if either of those fails

Comment: @Kodigas, first it shouldn't be in `@BeforeEach` because it never happens that you need the same kind of object for every test in a class. The data set up should happen as the first 1-3 lines of the test. Then if the set up is complicated, what I do is I created separate classes (e.g. TestObjectFactory, TestRepository) that do the job. So that the test are clean and don't duplicate a lot of code. But yes - the they will fail if your test code uses other repositories and those are broken. But that's a minor problem. A small price to pay for the reduced cost of maintenance.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev though, it's a pitty I can't `save()` an entity at the bottom of an object graph and see Hibernate figure out the right order of object persistence on its own

Comment: @Kodigas, yeah, I've experienced that when the object graph is too large. I simply created a TestRepository that would do this in the right order. Simply because I needed to create that kind of objects in hundreds (if not thousands) of tests.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev do you think some generic API is possible for [persisting a whole object graph by its node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77523406/are-there-out-of-the-box-solutions-for-persisting-a-whole-object-graph-by-its-no)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not strikingly obvious from the [official user guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html), but no, Hibernate doesn't guarantee that

> If the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto configuration is set to create, Hibernate is going to generate the following database schema:
>
> Example 323. Auto-generated database schema
>
> ```
> create table Customer (
>    id integer not null,
>    accountsPayableXrefId binary,
>    image blob,
>    name varchar(255),
>    primary key (id)
> )
> ```

Later in the guide...

> Example 335. @LazyGroup example
>
> ```
> @Entity public class Customer {
>
>   @Id     private Integer id;
>
>   private String name;
>
>   @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  private UUID accountsPayableXrefId;
>
>   @Lob    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  @LazyGroup("lobs")  private
> Blob image;
>
>   //Getters and setters are omitted for brevity
>
> }
> ```

Notice the order. The mismatch kind of implies that Hibernate creates table columns as it sees fit

Comment: Unless it or the JPA specification states there is an order to columns in DDL generation - there isn't any guarantee. Order shouldn't matter or be assumed to be under control by property positioning and is why JPA providers explicitly list columns they are selecting, inserting and updating.