# Are there out of the box solutions for persisting a whole object graph by its node?

Tags: java, jpa

Is there some library that roughly speaking implements this interface?

```java
public interface Persister {
    /** Persists the whole graph represented by graphNode */
    <T> void persistGraph(T graphNode);
}
```

I want to persist all JPA entities of any given graph in the right order without doing it manually. I hoped it would replace manual `@Sql` scripts, like the following one, in my tests (trimmed for brevity). It's error-prone and not OOP

```sql
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.operation_type
VALUES ('e3376ede-920b-4f48-abda-b565dd29a102', 'REPLENISHMENT', true);
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.operation_type
VALUES ('595cef39-29f3-4bf9-b9e1-30198a1d3df1', 'PAYMENT', false);
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.operation_type
VALUES ('f806a8b9-82dd-444f-9e93-429e1e42d480', 'TRANSFER', false);
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.operation_type
VALUES ('b02d27b1-3716-47c6-8160-d7e9ca4b6f6a', 'OTHER_EXPENDITURE', false);

INSERT INTO PUBLIC.PRODUCT
VALUES (1, 'product_name', 100, 100000, '810', 5, 10, false, true, true, false, 1, 5, true, 'some_details', 'ANNUITY',
        4, false, '2', '3.2', '5.0', false, 'CONSUMER'),
       (2, 'product_name', 200, 200000, '810', 2, 8, false, true, true, false, 1, 5, false, 'some_details', 'ANNUITY',
        4, false, '2', '3.2', '5.0', false, 'CONSUMER');

INSERT INTO PUBLIC.CREDIT_ORDER
VALUES ('00000000-0000-0001-0000-000000000001', '1', '00000000-0000-0001-0000-000000000001', 1, 'PENDING', 100000, 12,
        '2020-01-02', 20000, 20000, '123456');
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.CREDIT_ORDER
VALUES ('00000000-0000-0001-0000-000000000002', '2', '00000000-0000-0001-0000-000000000001', 1, 'PENDING', 200000, 12,
        '2020-04-23', 20000, 40000, '123456');
INSERT INTO PUBLIC.CREDIT_ORDER
VALUES ('00000000-0000-0001-0000-000000000003', '3', '00000000-0000-0001-0000-000000000001', 2, 'PENDING', 100000, 12,
        '2020-10-16', 20000, 20000, '123456');

-- and so on
```

Instead, I would initialize my database with `ddl-auto=create-drop` (doing away with a "schema.sql") and insert sample rows with a "persister" (doing away with a "data.sql")

```java
@DataJpaTest
@Import(value = BasicPersister.class)
class CardRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private CardRepository cardRepository;
    private DataGenerator dataGenerator; // this is another test utility that I wrote, it generates random entities, fully initialized
    @Autowired
    private Persister persister;
    private Card expectedCard;
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        dataGenerator = new BasicDataGenerator();
        expectedCard = dataGenerator.generateRandomCard();
        persister.persistGraph(expectedCard); // instead of all SQL inserts
    }
```

Just to give you an understanding of what our object graph looks like, I'll paste the skeletons of our service's entities (I kept only association and id fields):

```java
/* I'll include these class annotations only for 
the first entity to keep it short */

@Entity
@Table(name = "card")
@Getter
@Setter(AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Card {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Account account;
}
```

```java
public class Account {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "credit_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Credit credit;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    private List<Card> cards;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    private List<PaymentSchedule> paymentSchedules;
}
```

```java
public class PaymentSchedule {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private Account account;
}
```

```java
public class Credit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "credit")
    private Account account;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "credit")
    private Agreement agreement;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private CreditOrder creditOrder;
}
```

```java
public class Agreement {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "credit_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Credit credit;
}
```

```java
public class CreditOrder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;
}
```

```java
public class Product implements Serializable { // I have no idea why it implements Serializable

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    
    // it doesn't have any association fields
}
```

I want to be able to persist the entire graph by persisting an object of *any* of the types above (except for `Product` which is not linked with anything). All of the following should work similarly:

```java
     persister.persistGraph(dataGenerator.generateRandomAgreement());
     persister.persistGraph(dataGenerator.generateRandomCredit());
     persister.persistGraph(dataGenerator.generateRandomAccount());
```

Standard JPA won't help. Things like

```java
cardRepository.save(dataGenerator.generateRandomCard());
```

cause exceptions like

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find by.afinny.credit.entity.CreditOrder with id edbdc129-31a0-46db-a32e-fdcf472579d3
```

That is, Hibernate (the ORM provider I use) can't figure out on its own the right order of object persistence

For days, I tried to implement my own solution, and I even started to believe I was making progress (I counted foreign keys), but then I discovered some limitations, tried to address them, and my code turned into a bad-smelling heap real quick. Apparently, it's a bit too complicated for me. But what if I don't have to write any code, and there's already some open-source library that deals with that?

Comment: What do you mean by _in the right order_?  How are the `@Entity`'s defined?  How is that `Persister` interface related to jpa?

Comment: @AndrewS for example, it seems you can't persist a "many" entity before persisting a corresponding "one" entity. You get an exception "can't find <"one" entity> with id <id of the "one" object that you planned to persist second>"

Comment: JPA providers will do this - they are required to manage an object graph for persistence, which includes ordering inserts appropriately. What exactly have you tried - maybe start with a simple (flat) object model, make it work,  and expand it until it matches your desired object graph. Just going straight into it with a complex model might be a challenge. Course, you could always serialize the entire object to a singe clob/blob DB column

Comment: @Chris I tried simply calling save() on an object with all its relations set. It didn't work. It appears you can't persist an object with a foreign key pointing to a (yet) non-existent entity

Comment: * transient entity, that is

Comment: Right, if is transient. You might need to look at JPA tutorials on managed relationships and cascading the persist/merge operations through the graph, but this is a big part of where JPA shines. But you have to define those relationships in mappings. Maybe show a small example and we can help, but this does work, as any JPA tutorial with a reference (OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToMany etc) will prove. If you've got a circular FK in the table, that might be where there are problems, but this would be a problem in your SQL model itself as well.

Comment: @Chris Please see the edit

Comment: @Kodigas, it's strange that you get `EntityNotFoundException`. Do you by any chance clear EntityManager at some point? Or maybe you assign IDs manually somewhere?

Comment: You've got CascadeType.MERGE on some of the relationships, but not all, and you don't have any with the CascadeType.PERSIST. If this is a new graph, 'save' is a spring api that is likely determining your graph is new and so using EntityManager.persist. If you don't have the cascade persist option set on the graph, JPA will not cascade over the graph and pick up new entities being referenced.

Comment: @Chris that's the thing: I don't want to get dependent on whether cascade relationships are properly configured or not. Do you think I can achieve my goal?

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev no, to the best of my knowledge. I don't handle `EntityManager` manually, I use Spring Data. All ids in the graph are indeed set (that's the purpose of `DataGenerator`, it returns "fully initialized" objects, including persistence-related dependencies, entities and DTOs)

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77555439/can-i-ever-get-my-persister-work-its-intended-to-persist-a-graph-by-a-graph-n)

Comment: I don't quite understand. Your mappings are wrong for your stated intent and the error tells you the problem - you have a CreditOrder in the model that has ID already set somehow referenced in there and you've not told JPA how to handle it. Is it existing? Note that the only relationship you've shown to CreditOrder is from Credit, and you've told JPA to do nothing with the entity (no cascade persist/Merge options on it), which is likely the cause of your issue. If you don't fix that, then you have to manually save the CreditOrder instance to use it in your graph.

Comment: @Chris I want it to work with *any* cascade settings (I can't flex cascade rules based on what I need in tests). JPA can't do this so I asked for alternative solutions

Comment: Then no, there isn't a solution to read your object graph and decide you want cascade persist on all mappings. I'd suggest a test-only orm.xml mapping which would allow you to define cascade persist on all relationships (but it wouldn't be fun to write!), or look into your provider's native api to do something more declaratively just for the persistence unit you are using for testing if you are not able to write a class aware setup method that can persist the objects in your graph directly (ie iterate over your mappings and call save on every object).

Comment: @Kodigas I agree with Chris - this whole endeavor doesn't make sense. You're trying to replace a few simple lines of code with a complicated automagic approach Even if you do find a way to do what you want, I'd replace it with the code that explicitly persists the data.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev what lines of code? If you mean cascade attributes, then I can't do that. In business code, we don't necessarily want to e.g. save accounts when saving a card. It's not right to let business code follow test requirements

Comment: @Kodigas, no I meant writing some kind of `save()` method that accepts your high-level object and persists its dependencies in the right order.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev but then again, I need to write a separate `save()` for each entity. It also won't be able to be reused in other applications with completely different object graphs. Not nice

Comment: @Kodigas, how many types of these large entities you have? I usually have 1-2 per project, while the rest are small and the cascades work fine. So I wonder what's your situation.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev we have more or less one graph, but I want to persist it by any of its seven nodes (or rather, six since `Product` is not linked with anything)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's where the discussion stems for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77485657/hibernate-swaps-columns-around-when-creating-a-table-why-on-earth-does-it-do-it?noredirect=1#comment136669631_77485657). Most of the time Hibernate can figure out the order on its own:

1. It uses the information in cascades to determine what fields to store first. So if you say `ClassA.fieldB` has `cascade="persist"`, then ORM knows that `fieldB` has to be `INSERT`ed before the owning object.
2. Additionally, it uses the collection `inverse` / `mappedBy` in order to determine whether elements of the collection can be `INSERT`ed w/o filling the FK (which potentially could be a non-null column and this will cause errors); or maybe we should first persist the parent object, and then insert the collection element with the FK already filled.

I can't think of other factors right now that could be important, but these seem to be most critical anyway. Now, if all these were set up correctly, ORM should be able to figure out the right order of persisting.

However, in practice there will be situations where a graph of objects can't be persisted because cascades are not (and must not!) be set up. E.g. if you have a User who lives in some Country, then your user can't be responsible for persisting Country, and vice versa.

I think it's also possible to create a conflicting situation, like circular dependency, where ORMs will persist entities not in the order you hoped for. But I can't remember if in my practice that was the case or I simply was too lazy to find the cause :)

All in all, I don't think that this problem *can* be solved for a general case (with ORM or not). Instead of persisting the graph dynamically, I'd fall back to explicitly persisting the objects in the right order if your graph is so complex.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Can you please see my last edit?